# React - props undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, single-page-application

I am trying to pass a  pass down `id` from `getUsers()` to a child component as a `prop`.

**App.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import About from './components/About';
import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Form from './components/forms/Form';
import Logout from './components/Logout';
import UserStatus from './components/UserStatus';
import Seeds from './components/Seeds';
import Message from './components/Message';    

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      users: [],
      title: 'Project',
      isAuthenticated: false,
      messageName: null,
      messageType: null,
      restaurant: '',
      email: '',
      id: '',
      username: '',
      active: '',
      admin: '',   
    };
    this.logoutUser = this.logoutUser.bind(this);
    this.loginUser = this.loginUser.bind(this);
    this.createMessage = this.createMessage.bind(this);
    this.removeMessage = this.removeMessage.bind(this);
    this.userStatus = this.userStatus.bind(this);
  };
  componentWillMount() {
    if (window.localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    };
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.getUsers();
    this.userStatus();
  };
  getUsers() {
    axios.get(`${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/users`)
    .then((res) => { this.setState({ users: res.data.data.users }); })
    .catch((err) => { });
  };
  logoutUser() {
    window.localStorage.clear();
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false });
  };
  loginUser(token) {
    window.localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true });
    this.getUsers();
    this.createMessage('Welcome', 'success');
  };
  userStatus(event) {
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/auth/status`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => { 
      console.log(res.data)  
      console.log(res.data.data) 
      this.setState({
        restaurant: res.data.data.restaurant,
        email: res.data.data.email,
        id: res.data.data.id,
        username: res.data.data.username,
        active: String(res.data.data.active),
        admin: String(res.data.data.admin),
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
  createMessage(name='Sanity Check', type='success') {
    this.setState({
      messageName: name,
      messageType: type
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.removeMessage();
    }, 3000);
  };
  removeMessage() {
    this.setState({
      messageName: null,
      messageType: null
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <NavBar
          title={this.state.title}
          isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
        />
        <section className="section">
          <div className="container">
            {this.state.messageName && this.state.messageType &&
              <Message
                messageName={this.state.messageName}
                messageType={this.state.messageType}
                removeMessage={this.removeMessage} 
              />
            }
            <div className="columns">
              <div className="column is-half">
                <br/>
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/' render={() => (
                    <SpotifyAuth
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/about' component={About}/>
                  <Route exact path='/register' render={() => (
                    <Form
                      formType={'Register'}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      loginUser={this.loginUser}
                      createMessage={this.createMessage} 
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/login' render={() => (
                    <Form
                      formType={'Login'}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      loginUser={this.loginUser}
                      createMessage={this.createMessage} 
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/logout' render={() => (
                    <Logout
                      logoutUser={this.logoutUser}
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/status' render={() => (
                    <UserStatus
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                    />
                  )} />
                  <Route exact path='/seeds' render={() => (
                    <Seeds
                      isAuthenticated={this.state.isAuthenticated}
                      userStatus={this.userStatus}
                    />
                  )} />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    )
  }
};

export default App;
```

**Seeds.jsx**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Seeds extends Component{
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
        restaurant:'',      
        email: '',
        id: '',
        username: '',
        active: '',
        admin: '',
        template:'',
      formSeeds:{
        type1:'',
        type2:'',
        type3:'',
      },
      formEditMenu:{
        item:'',
        item2:'',
        item3:'',
      }
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitSeeds = this.handleSubmitSeeds.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmitItems = this.handleSubmitItems.bind(this);
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.isAuthenticated) {
      this.getSeeds();
    }
  };
  getSeeds(event) {
    const {userStatus} = this.props
    const options = {
      url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/seeds/${userStatus.id}`,
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.authToken}`
      }
    };
    return axios(options)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res.data.data)
      this.setState({
        restaurant: res.data.data[0].restaurant,
        id: res.data.data[0].id,
        template: res.data.data[0].content
      })
      console.log(userStatus.id);
    })    
    .catch((error) => { console.log(error); });
  };
  handleChange(event){
    const objformSeeds = this.state.formSeeds;
    objformSeeds[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(objformSeeds);

    const formEditMenu = this.state.formEditMenu;
    formEditMenu[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    this.setState(formEditMenu);
    }
  handleSubmitSeeds(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {userStatus} = this.props
    const data = {
      type1: this.state.formSeeds.type1,
      type2: this.state.formSeeds.type2,
      type3: this.state.formSeeds.type3,
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/handle_seeds/${userStatus.id}`;
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
  };
  handleSubmitCoffees(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const {userStatus} = this.props
    const data = {
      item:  this.state.formEditMenu.item,
      item2: this.state.formEditMenu.items2,
      items3: this.state.formEditMenu.items3,
    };
    const url = `${process.env.REACT_APP_WEB_SERVICE_URL}/edit_menu/${userStatus.id}`;
    axios.post(url, data)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
      });
    };

    render(){
            var __html = this.state.template;
        var template = { __html: __html };

        return (
           <div id="parent">
            <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={template}/>
              <form>
                <input type='text' name='name' onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleSubmitItems} />
              </form>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Seeds;
```

but I'm getting userStatus `undefined`.

```
XHR failed loading: GET "http://localhost/seeds/undefined".
```

[image]

> console.log(userStatus):

```
userStatus(event) {
    const options = {
      url: "".concat("http://localhost", "/auth/status"),
      method: 'get',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Authoriza…
```

what am I missing?

Comment: you mean youre trying to pass userStatus down?

Comment: yes, correct. from app to seeds

Comment: ok edit your post it says youre trying to pass down getUsers().

Comment: can you console.log(userStatus)? and screen shot

Comment: done, please refer to edit

Comment: console.log(userStatus) in Seeds.jsx returns undefined

Comment: okay don't console.log(userStatus.id) console.log(userStatus)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you pass down the id only because you using this.userStatus is the function

`userStatus={this.userStatus}`

You need to change to

`userStatus={this.state.id}`

Comment: Can you try to console.log on parent component to see you have the data or not before pass down to the child ?